# Decrypting javascript binary to text using openpgp

Tags: javascript, encryption, pgp, openpgp, openpgp.js

the problem is that when decoding an image for example, I get a corrupted binary data, I've tried to convert it to base64, but it is invalid to display, is there a solution to decrypt pgp encrypted images valid

I am using this library, tell me it is valid for decrypting binary? http://openpgpjs.org/

**ENCRYPT:**

```
var key = request.data.publicKey;
var publicKey = openpgp.key.readArmored(key);
var base64Message = request.data.message;//btoa(request.data.message); // encoding binary data directly
openpgp.encryptMessage(publicKey.keys, base64Message).then(function(pgpMessage) {
    console.log('encrypted');
    console.log(pgpMessage);
    sendResponse({result: pgpMessage});
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

**DECRYPTING**:

```
var key = openpgp.key.readArmored(request.data.privateKey); 
console.log(key);

if(key.keys.length > 0)
{
    key = key.keys[0];
    key.decrypt(request.data.password);
    var message = openpgp.message.readArmored(request.data.message); // error can't read pgp encoded binary data

    openpgp.decryptMessage(key,message).then(function(plaintext) {
        //do stuff...plaintext - is binary data in text
    });
}
```

I encode binary directly, and then trying to decode but I get an error that:

> Unknown ASCII armor type

Comment: @ArtjomB.using this library there are examples of encrypt/decrypt http://openpgpjs.org/

Comment: You need to add the code that you personally used to encrypt the image that you now can't decrypt. If you are running this in a browser and want to display the image as base64, you should convert it to base64 before you encrypt it. Then when it's decrypted it will be ready to use.

Comment: @DanPrince hey look I've added examples of how I encode binary directly, and then trying to decode but I get an error that: Unknown ASCII armor type

Answer (score 0):

Base 64 is used to wrap bytes into an ASCII armor so you can transport the binary data over a text oriented interface. What you need to transport is the ciphertext that seems to be written to `pgpMessage`. You should base 64 encode the ciphertext in there, you should not base 64 encode the plaintext message.